# Настройка rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

```
RewriteRule ^order/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=order&name=$1 [L]
```

У меня все работает как надо, только [site.ru/order](http://site.ru/order) (без слэша на конце) возвращает ошибку 404. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для СЕО лучше, чтобы каждому контенту соотв. только один URL. Будем считать "правильным" URL со слешем в конце. Вместо `site.ru` впишите ваш адрес сайта.

```
# Вар. 1 - должно начинаться с order и заканчиваться слешем
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^order/(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^order/(.+)/$ index.php?do=order&name=$1 [L]

# Вар. 2 - пришли без слеша в конце - редиректить на "правильный"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^order
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: еще вот так попробовал:

RewriteRule ^order(/?)+$ index.php?do=order [L]
RewriteRule ^order/(.*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=order&name=$1 [L]

Но тут не работает такая ссылка: site.ru/order/name/ (со слэшэм на конце)

Comment: нашел рабочий вариант:

RewriteRule ^order(/?)+$ index.php?do=order [L]
RewriteRule ^order/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=order&name=$1 [L]

Comment: Обновил ответ. Надо разрешать только один URL на страницу, поэтому, если пришли с "неправильным" -  без слеша в конце, то надо 301 редирект делать им на правильный, со слешем.